# How can I reassign a comment in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, google-slides

Is it possible to reassign a comment to another person? For example, to assign the comment to a person who commented on the comment thread as well.

[image]

Comment: But then I am losing the entire comment history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve reassigning a task from an existing comment thread by adding a new comment starting with +[email address] of who you want to assign/reassign the item to.

As you fill in the email address of the designee, Google Docs will show a checkbox prompting you to "reassign" the comment/task.

Below is an example screenshot of Google Docs prompting you to assign/reassign a task.
[image: Google Doc task assignment example]

Comment: for some reason I do not see this checkbox after entering such comment

Comment: I tested the feature on November 20, 2018 and can confirm this description still applies.  I updated original answer with a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

You can only assign a comment thread to a person by mentioning them in the comment text using the `+[email]` notation (tip: you can use the `@` sign during typing and it will be replaced with the `+` sign). When you do so, on the bottom of the comment Window you will see a checkbox appear to assign the thread to that person (before you save).

If you mention multiple people in the comment, the checkbox will be completed with a dropdown where you can select the person to whom you want to assign the thread, chosen from the ones you mention in the comment. A thread can only be assigned to one person at a time.

This works both in a new comment (to assign) or in a reaction on an already assigned thread (to reassign). You don't need to be the assignee in order to reassign the thread, you just need to reply.

However, if the initial message was not assigned, there is no way to assign the thread afterwards. Not even by editing the original message. This also makes it so that you cannot assign threads linked to suggestions, since the initial message (the suggestion) is not assigned.